# Send response back from NodeJS Server to client side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I have created a HTTP server in NodeJS using the `http.createServer(...)` function. From a client side JavaScript file, I have sent a query using the `POST` method on the localhost url. The server has successfully received the data from the client but now I am unable to send a response for e.g, a message, "Success" / JSON file back to the client. I have tried many approaches using `res.end(message)` and `res.write()` but it keeps stopping the server after `end()` is called and my client throws errors on the console. I am running my HTML file using the Live Server on VS Code.
Here are the codes:

client.js

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let inputVal;

function load(url, callback) {
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(xhr.readyState);
        callback(xhr.response);
      }
    }
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    responseType = "";
    var body = "name="+inputVal;
    console.log(body);
    xhr.send(body);
}

function alert_user(data)
{
    window.alert("Response Received");
    console.log("OK");
    console.log(data);
}

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // to prevent reloading
    inputVal=document.getElementById("name").value;
    load("http://localhost:3000/", alert_user);
});
```

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var qs = require('querystring');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method == "POST") {
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        var post = qs.parse(body);
        req.on('end', () => {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.end('Success');
        });
    }
}).listen(3000);
```

I am running my server from the CMD and HTML file from VS Code Live Server.

[image: Console error]

**When I use the server without `res.end()` and continue to do some operations with my data, it does everything correctly with no CORS errors on the client side JS.**

I had also tried creating the server using the Express framework and it works perfectly when I use `res.json()` or similar to this and using `fetch().then().then()` on the client side where it receives the json file as a response.
I am writing the code for server on NodeJS as I want to use other functionalities of NodeJS along with creating a server.
Can anyone please suggest the possible errors and how to debug them and get this working only using XMLHttpRequest?

**Edit:** The console now shows the request was complete by setting the `readyState` to 4 but I receive an empty response from the server.

Comment: I get the vibe like you are ignoring the CORS problem - a feature in web browsers which blocks requests that don't follow the *same-origin policy* that is, like in your error-image a request from `localhost:5500` to `localhost:3000` is considered *cross-origin request*. It's a simple fix that has been answered so many times on stackoverflow. If I write an answer we both will just get downvotes.

Comment: That aside, I suggest you to install [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) library that makes coding in Node.js so much easier and shorter. It's good to start with vanilla Node and learn how it works under the hood, but soon you have to make your life easier and just use it with Express.

Comment: @Aleksandar Yes I have tried to put aside the CORS problem by hosting it on VS Code's Live Server and fixed it for now. To be put in short, I am simply trying to replicate Express's `res.json()` functionality in Vanilla NodeJS. Yes, using express, I was able to send a response back and receive at the client but again ignoring CORS (which I am ignoring for now).

Comment: Also, your `function alert` overwrites the `window.alert`: Both are the same thing and since you call `alert` inside `alert`, you get an endless recursion. Give your function a different name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was again with the CORS :-(

Here's the final working code...

client.js

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let inputVal;
let searchBtn = document.getElementById("searchBtn");

function load(url, callback) {
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(xhr.readyState);
        callback(xhr.responseText);
      }
    }
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    responseType = "";
    var body = "name="+inputVal;
    console.log(body);
    xhr.send(body);
}

function alert_user(data)
{
    window.alert("Response Received");
    console.log("OK");
    console.log(data);
}

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // to prevent reloading
    inputVal=document.getElementById("name").value;
    load("http://localhost:3000/", alert_user);
});
```

server.js

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    if (req.method == "POST") {
        //other operations
        res.end("Done");
    }
}).listen(3000);
```

This works and the client gets a response at his console :-)

(Everything is running on the VS Code's Live Server)